# Entity Framework issue with plugin ASP.MVC architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm implementing pluggable MVC application described in that article: http://blog.longle.net/2012/03/29/building-a-composite-mvc3-application-with-pluggable-areas/#plugin

Basically it has one main web application (ASP.MVC 4) and some amount of sub-web applications which use some class libraries as their layers (DAL, BLL).

I'm facing following problem. I have entity model (edmx) defined in SubProject1.DataAccess class library. Then I have SubProject1.Web project and finally I have main Web proejct. SubProject1.Web has following postbuild event declared:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)\Views" "$(TargetDir)\SubProject1\Views\" /s /i /y
```

It has also main web application `\Areas` directory set as output path.

When I try to access some entity from DbContext object the Entity Framework throws the following exception:

> Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Stacktrace:

> at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String
>   assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry,
>   MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)    at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource..ctor(String
>   originalPath, String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1
>   uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)    at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String
>   path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension,
>   ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) 
>   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path,
>   ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1
>   uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)    at
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths)    at
>   System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()    at
>   System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)    at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean
>   initializeAllCollections)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection
>   connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   SubProject1.DataAccess.DataSources.OracleDb.OracleDb.get_Administrators()
>   in
>   c:\somepath\SubProject1.DataAccess\DataSources\OracleDb\OracleDb.cs:line
>   60    at SubProject1.Web.Controllers.SubTestController.Index() in
>   d:\somepath\SubProject1.Web\Controllers\SubTestController.cs:line 16
>
>   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _)    at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()

It seems that EF can't find location of edmx file. Does anyone know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Put the proper Entity Framework connection string in your web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each module has it's own EF model, each of the connection strings for those entities needs to be in the master web project where all of the module's views get copied into.  Based on that error, it appears the connection string that points to the metadata of the files is not in that final config file.